# Openshift Postgresql connection error:

Tags: java, postgresql

***Edited***:  I checked the log file, and the URL message is:
`Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'postgresql://adminxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@10.1o.1o.10:5432'`

I get the following error with postgres on openshift (9.x)

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`
`java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)`

My URL is ${OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL}

This exact build works on my local host (different URL, of course), and I can see the openshift jar in the correct place in the war file

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, "No suitable driver". Maybe, try to install proper SQL driver?

Comment: This webapp works fine on my local machine with postgres, and the jar file is there.

Comment: "*'postgresql://adminxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx@10.1o.1o.10:5432'*" - a JDBC URL must start with `jdbc:`

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the URL in the environment variable on Openshift does not work.

See here:
http://mikeski.net/blog/index.php?/archives/17-Postgres-and-JBoss-on-openshift.html